# Calling std::function causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Here's my code:

```
void StoreHelper::buyProduct(int productId, const std::function<void()>& succeded, const std::function<void()>& failed) {

    //dummy code to wait 2 seconds, it'll send a request here
    Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->getChildren().at(0)->runAction(Sequence::createWithTwoActions(DelayTime::create(2.0f), CallFunc::create([&, succeded](){

        succeded(); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    })));
}
```

Calling `succeded()` in buyProduct main code works. But when I call it 2 seconds later, even though I pass the function in the capture list crashes the app with EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

[image]

However if I store the std::function in the class instance like this:

```
void StoreHelper::buyProduct(int productId, const std::function<void()>& succeded, const std::function<void()>& failed) {

    succededCallback = succeded;

    //dummy code to wait 2 seconds, it'll send a request here
    Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->getChildren().at(0)->runAction(Sequence::createWithTwoActions(DelayTime::create(2.0f), CallFunc::create([&](){

        succededCallback();

    })));
}
```

it works, but not always. Sometimes it crashes with the same error anyway.

What's the cause of this? Is it because it gets recycled from the memory? How can I prevent it? It'd be the best I won't have to store the `std::function` inside class instance, but rather just pass it to the lambda function.

Edit:

here's simplified version of the code without using cocos2d-x actions:

```
void StoreHelper::buyProduct(int productId, const std::function<void()>& succeded, const std::function<void()>& failed) {

    std::async(std::launch::async, [&, succeded] () {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds{2});

        succeded();
    });
}
```

usage:

```
buyProduct(12345, [&]() {            
    //success
}, [&]() {
    //failed
});
```

And this simplified version works! Can this be a threading issue?

Comment: What happens if you change the lambda capture from `&` to `=`?  Is this a asynchronous function call?  Any chance we can get a [mcve]?

Comment: Same crash occurs in both cases with `=`. Strange, when I change it do std::async and call sleep_for instead of using cocos2d-x action to simulate a 2 seconds sleep it works just with passing `succeded` in the capture list.